# Target elements excluding certain others

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a 2-columns table formed by a list of divs and I would like to **target all the divs on the right**. Using :nth-of-type(even) does not work in my case because I have some divs that span on a 100% width and so they alter the cascade order. The desired result is shown in the following picture:

[image]

```
<section class="container">
  <div>#1</div>
  <div>#2</div>
  <div class="fullWidth">#3</div>
  <div>#4</div>
  <div>#5</div>
  <div>#6</div>
  <div>#7</div>
  <div class="fullWidth">#8</div>
  <div>#9</div>
  <div>#10</div>
</section>
```

```
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 20px;
  outline: 2px solid lightgrey;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container > div {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  outline: 1px solid bisque;
  background-color: #c5c8d5;
}
div.fullWidth {
  width:100%;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  background-color: lightsalmon
}
```

I've tried adjacent and siblings selector, plus a combination of ::not(), ::last-of-type and ::first-of-type

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Not sure if there is a good way to do this. If you managed to add a `fullWidth` class to some of those divs during the generation of this HTML, then you should probably be able to add odd/even classes to the other divs as well?

Comment: The desired logic and the layout are not lining up this way. `table` instead of `section` would be better suited for use with `nth-col` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-col). Otherwise this will need complex workarounds with programmatic class tagging or JS checking relative `x` coordinates.

Comment: Well, the goal was to format the table automatically. I can set every class manually but this is not always the case, especially if you generate the table with a Vue,js v-for or Twig or React equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the new `nth-child()` selector by excluding the fullwidth items from the selection

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 20px;
  outline: 2px solid lightgrey;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container > div {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  outline: 1px solid bisque;
  background-color: #c5c8d5;
}
div.fullWidth {
  width:100%;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  background-color: lightsalmon
}

.container > div:nth-child(even of :not(.fullWidth)) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div>#1</div>
  <div>#2</div>
  <div class="fullWidth">#3</div>
  <div>#4</div>
  <div>#5</div>
  <div>#6</div>
  <div>#7</div>
  <div class="fullWidth">#8</div>
  <div>#9</div>
  <div>#10</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Whoa. This is like 4th level css-fu!

Comment: That definitely saved my day, thank you

Comment: Nice! I was close to getting there but didn't know you could do `even of`, much simpler than what I was trying, I'm saving this one for later ;)